# Simple dropdown div

Tags: jquery, html, css, dropdown

I'm struggling with a simple dropdown link. 
I have a div with a text link and when clicking this text should appear another div with text information.

So far the HTML is:

```
<div id="about" class="fluid">
    <a href="#">About & Contact</a>

    <div id="dropdown" class="fluid"><blockquote>
          We are a bla bla...</div>
</div>
```

I used CSS in order to hide the dropdown div:

```
#dropdown {display: none;}
```

And the jQuery function is:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#about').each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){
                $(this).siblings('#dropdown').slideToggle(300);            
            });
        });
    });​​
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Your javascript implies that you have more elements with the same ID, which is invalid, ID's are unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way could be to use below code

```
$("#about  a").click(function() {
    $("#dropdown").toggle();
    return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/santoshjoshi/n0yeo9nb/

Comment: Thanks @Arnau. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Keep contributing to this platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#about").find("a:first-child").click(function() {
$("#dropdown").toggle();
return false;
});
```

use this as your js. here i used find selector.. as this faster comparatively to other selectors.